# Capistrano: ExecJS error when deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, capistrano, capistrano3, execjs

I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and Debian 8.5 and I'm following [this guide](http://wiki.douglasqsantos.com.br/doku.php/deploying_a_rails_app_on_debian_jessie_with_capistrano_nginx_and_puma_en) to deploy my Rails app.

When I deploy my app, I get ExecJS error. [See my deployment logs here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7cbe0f3733b07f09787c1b6c808db44e).

What I've done but doesn't work:

1. Installing NodeJS on server
2. Add execjs and therubyracer in Gemfile
3. Install execjs and therubyracer in server

All 3 not working for me.

What should I do? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally? Are you getting any errors?

It seems something wrong with your JS file.

Since the unexpected '#' character was found on line 13941 of your example then you'll find your comments on that same line.

Answer (score 0):

The error message of note seems to be `ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected character '#' (line: 13941, col: 0, pos: 384252)`. You have a hash (`#`) char somewhere in you JS which is not being understood by the JS parser. It says that the char is on line 13,941, position 384,252. That sounds like minified code to me, so it may be vendored JS or JS that is in the middle of being processed.

I'd suggest auditing all of your JS for the `#` symbol. Grep or The Silver Searcher will be useful.